# Can't access that on routing Laravel

Tags: routes, laravel-4

I am trying out Laravel and I am in a little jam although I have not being able to get passed it.

I saved data into database which was quite successful but I want to redirect to another page with some information. Redirect was successful but I can't access the data.

My codes are below;

mycontroller.php

```
 public function AddSales(){

   $userid  = Input::get("userid");//user ID

  //insert details sales
    $sales=new Sales();
    $sales->member_id=$userid;
    $sales->sales='0';
    $sales->pay_month='none';
    $sales->pay_year='0';
    $sales->pay_date='none';
    $sales->save();

    $newmember = Member::select('lname','oname')->where('user_id', '=',$userid)->get();


    return Redirect::route("upload")->with("newMember",$newmember);

}
```

Route.php

```
//upload passport page
Route::get('upload', array("as" => "upload",'before' => 'auth', function(){
    return View::make('user.uploadpassport');
}));
```

uploadpassport.blade.php

```
@foreach ($newMember as $newMembers)
   {{$newMembers->lname}}
@endforeach
```

note: this code is reduced for brevity

The error I encounter is that $newMember is not defined, although the data is saved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the route upload you need to get the flash message and assign it to the view, you can get the messages from the session.

Laravel docs:

```
Note: Since the with method flashes data to the session, you may retrieve the data using the typical Session::get method.
```

Comment: It is actually an array of data that I needed to display. If I use View::make('')->with('newmember',$newmember); it works fine but it has a problem of re-submitting the form again on page refresh